# Resizing boot partition

Tags: fedora, partition, lvm, luks

I need to expand my `/boot` partition to install updates. I have 200MB `/boot` partition and then I have 2 LVM partitions - `/home` and `/` encrypted by LUKS.

Is it possible to shrink LVM partitions by 300MB and expand `/boot` to 500MB?

Normally I would do things like this in GParted, but it doesn't support LVM. I'm a little bit confused about option to have LUKS over LVM or  LVM over LUKS. I believe I have LUKS over LVM, but I'm not 100% sure.

I'm using Fedora 24

Comment: `/boot` is most likely not a part of the VG (volume group) in your installation. So you can't just simply reduce the LVs and resize `/boot`.

Comment: Hmm I see. Does it mean it will be more complicated (and possibly data-loss risky) or is it completely impossible?

Comment: Not impossible, but will be very hard. You may lose date. If you have another identical disk, take a backup of the original disk using dd.

Comment: The output of `lsblk` would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 1 large LUKS partition that contains LVM physical volume which is subdivided into 2 LVM logical volumes.

Manually shrinking LVM partitions is fairly long and error prone process.

One thing you can try is to compile (or find a snapshot) of KDE Partition Manager which can resize both LUKS and LVM.

Note that currently released version of KDE Partition Manager 2.2 can only handle LUKS but not LVM.